# Highcharts xrange styling

Tags: css, highcharts, xrange

I want to display my highchart like below. I'm using an 'xrange' type highchart for this. I'm trying to display an event for each data point where there will be a start data and an end date.

[image]

So far i was able to create this chart using xrange type, but I was not able to get the exact display like the above image.
Below is my code,

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0,
            color: 'rgba(230, 141, 11, 0.5)',
            pointWidth: 10
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            color: 'rgba(228, 53, 70, 0.5)',
            y: 0,
            pointWidth: 10
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
            color: 'rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5)',
            y: 0,
            pointWidth: 10
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
            color: 'rgba(40, 147, 164, 0.5)',
            y: 0,
            pointWidth: 10
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]

});
```

```css
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Is there a way to change my implementation in highchart to get output like the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a transparent color for points and use border color to achieve the wanted result. Use `xAxis` to add the black line under the series.

```
xAxis: {
    visible: true,
    tickLength: 0,
    lineWidth: 6,
    lineColor: '#000',
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},
series: [{
    borderWidth: 6,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        y: 0,
        color: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(230, 141, 11, 0.5)'
    }, ...],
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8p0weh7s/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.borderColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.enabled